# How to add an ID value to a div append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a "fault-counter" that stores a value of all incorrect answers. It starts at 0 and goes up one for every wrong answer.

I'm looking to have the results screen show the amount of faults you've made. So if the div #fault-counter has a value of 3, the end text will say "Sorry, you've made 3 faults!"

This is the code I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
var faultcounter = $('#fault-counter');

$('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + $('#fault-counter') + ' faults!</h1>');
```

**EDIT:**
The HTML for the 'fault-counter' looks like this:

```
<div id="fault-display">
          <div id="fault-counter">0</div>
          <h3>FAULTS</h3>
        </div>
```

And the jQuery being used to increase the value for every wrong answer is this:

```
$(".failQuestion").click(function(){
    $('#fault-counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
  });
```

Comment: What kind of HTML element is your fault-counter?

Comment: Just add .text() to the end of $('#fault-counter')

Comment: If its an `input`  then use `$('#fault-counter').val()` otherwise `$('#fault-counter').text()`

Comment: The HTML element is this:
`<div id="fault-display">
  <div id="fault-counter">0</div>
  <h3>FAULTS</h3>
</div>`

and the way I'm increasing the value of the numbers is this:
`$(".failQuestion").click(function(){
    $('#fault-counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
  });`

Unfortunately using .val() results in no number being displayed and .text() always displays the default 0. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, as your fault-counter is a div than .text() should suffice.

```
 $('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + $('#fault-counter').text() + ' faults!</h1>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var faultcounter = $('#fault-counter').val();

$('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + faultcounter + ' faults!</h1>');
```

You'll have to grab the value from `#fault-counter` using `.val()` and then append the variable, instead of the jQuery selector to the `#slickQuiz`.
That being said, i'm assuming you're using an input or select for `#fault-counter`. Otherwise `.text()` would be sufficient

Comment: The HTML element is this:

`<div id="fault-display"> <div id="fault-counter">0</div> <h3>FAULTS</h3> </div>`

and the way I'm increasing the value of the numbers is this:

`$(".failQuestion").click(function(){ $('#fault-counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 }); });`

Unfortunately using .val() results in no number being displayed and .text() always displays the default 0. :(

Comment: Can you post all code you currently have in a codepen / jsfiddle so I can have a good look at it?

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, you've been awesome! But I've found that this works!

`$('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + $('#fault-counter').text() + ' faults!</h1>');`

Answer (score 1):

i think there is a problem :

```
   var faultcounter = $('#fault-counter');

  if $('#fault-counter') is a input control then use "VAL()" : 

    $('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + $('#fault-counter').val() + ' faults!</h1>');
```

OR

if $('#fault-counter') is a DIV control then use "html()" :

```
    $('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + $('#fault-counter').html() + ' faults!</h1>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var faultcounter = $('#fault-counter').text();

$('#slickQuiz').prepend('<h1>Sorry, you have ' + faultcounter + ' faults!</h1>');
```

This is what you want to use because you mentioned that `#fault-counter` is a div. If that's so then you'll want to use the `.text` method. If it's an input or textarea then use the `.val` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D